# Why am I getting different results?

Tags: c#

```
string s = "this is a test";
var result = s.ToCharArray().Reverse();
result.ToString();                               
Console.Write(result.ToArray()); //output = test a si sith  
but with code : Console.WriteLine(result.ToString().ToArray());
```

and with code:

```
result.ToString(); 
result.ToArray(); 
Console.Write(result);
```

The output is :

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+ReverseIterator`1[System.Char]
```

Comment: That's what `ToString()` does when it hasn't been overridden; it just shows the name of the runtime type of the object. See duplicate. Your first example works fine because there's [`Write()` method overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write#System_Console_Write_System_Char___) that accepts the `char[]` returned by `ToArray()`. Note that you're not calling `ToString()` on the thing you're printing in that example, while you are in the second example, and in the third example, the `Write()` method calls `ToString()` implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

```
var result = s.ToCharArray().Reverse(); //Here type of result is IEnumerable<char>
result.ToString();//Calls default implementation of `.ToString()` method
```

When You call `ToString()`, it returns resultant string from overridden `ToString()` function. If it is not implemented in the given class then it returns its base implementation where it returns the fully qualified name of the variable.

In your case, `.ToString()` function is not overridden in Enumerable class, so it returns `system.linq.Enumerable+ReverseIterator1[System.Char]` as it is fully qualified name of `result` variable.

If you want to print elements of `result`, then try with [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0), like

```
var result = s.ToCharArray().Reverse();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", result));  //Instead of result.ToString()
```

---

MSDN Documentation: [Object.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#remarks)

> Object.ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework.
> It converts an object to its string representation so that it is
> suitable for display. (For information about formatting support in the
> .NET Framework, see Formatting Types.) **Default implementations of
> the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the
> object's type.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference because the line:

```
result.ToString();
```

does not contribute to what is eventually printed at all. Calling `ToString` like that creates the string

```
"System.Linq.Enumerable+ReverseIterator`1[System.Char]"
```

And **discards it**. Note that this does not somehow reassigns that string to `result`, as you might think.

So you are essentially comparing:

```
Console.Write(result.ToArray());
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString().ToArray());
```

Note that `result` is an `IEnumerable<char>` containing the sequence of characters in the string `s`, but reversed. `result.ToString().ToArray()` means "call `ToString` on `result`, then call `ToArray` on the return value of `ToString`".

Calling `ToString` on the `IEnumerable<char>` that is `result` doesn't give you the characters that are in the sequence, but instead just the type name (this is the default `ToString` implementation):

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+ReverseIterator`1[System.Char]
```

Then you call `ToArray` on that string to convert it to a `char[]`, and there is [an overload of `Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char___) that prints the characters in a `char[]`.

`Console.Write(result.ToArray());` is similar, except you don't convert the `IEnumerable<char>` to a not-very-useful string, and directly convert the sequence of `char`s to a `char[]`, so *that* `char[]` actually has the characters of `s` in reverse order.

[`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-5.0#System_Console_Write_System_Char___) also has an overload that prints the contents of a `char[]`, which you then call.